# What is known about graphs that permit only one colouring?

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, graph-colorings

Some graphs ($K_n$ or $K_n$ minus any one edge, for instance) only permit one minimal colouring up to different labels of the colours.  Is there anything known about these kind of graphs?  I can think of a number of examples of such graphs (mostly just $K_{n,m}$ minus an edge or two), but I can't think of any general statements I can make about them.

I was just wondering if there was any prior research into this as I couldn't find anything.  It could be that it's trivial (in which case I'd be interested in whether there's anything known about the number of minimal colourings).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a bit hard to give a comprehensive answer without knowing exactly what sort of properties you are after, but here is a start. Such graphs are called uniquely colorable graphs (see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Uniquelyk-ColorableGraph.html) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniquely_colorable_graph)). For the case of two colors they are characterized as the connected bipartite graphs, but for higher numbers of colors no such characterization is known.

In a uniquely $k$-colorable graph of $n$ vertices, the number of edges is at least $(k-1)n-\binom{k}{2}$, but otherwise they don't have to be extremely dense as your examples suggest. In fact for any $n$ there exist graphs with $n$ vertices that are uniquely 3-colorable [and have no triangles](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X9390220N). The lower bound for the number of edges is achieved at any [$(k-1)$-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-tree) (alternatively maximal graph of treewidth $k-1$).

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what I was looking for - a place to start. :)  Thanks!